# Arranging balls in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $m$ white balls and $n$ black balls. We arrange them randomly in a row.
>
> Let $k_1,\ldots, k_j \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k_1 + \cdots + k_j = m$.
>
> What's the probability the balls arrangement is:
>
> $k_1$ white balls, 1 black ball, $k_2$ white balls, 1 black ball ...

The answer is $\frac{m!n!}{(n+m)!}$. The denominator is easy to understand, that's all the possibilities. How to understand the numerator?

Comment: are $k_i's$ fixed?

Comment: Yes, they are fixed.

Comment: As all the white balls are visually the same one, and the same for the black ones, the denominator is not what you are thinking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The answer is $\frac{1}{\binom{m+n}{n}}$.

Comment: Oh I see where was my problem. Thank you!